# Zen theme not compatible with IE8?

Tags: theming

I am using a zen theme, the default styles and template and while the Main content displays correctly in Firefox, it is all the way to the left in IE.

In firefox, Navigation menu on top, sidebar on the left, main content on the right.
In IE, Main content area on top, with navigation menu underneath and sidebar first underneat that. All left align...

What am I missing?

I just overrode all the css and everything and it is still displaying the same...

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I fixed the issue by setting the bandwidth optimization to: Aggregate and compress CSS files." said kine456.
kine456 answered his own question.

This is because js files like respond.js that comes with the zen theme must get applied after you aggregate the css files for it to look correctly in ie8. I'm pretty sure its documented in the theme's readme.

Comment: This makes development more difficult but I had the same issue. In IE8 my theme broke but was fixed when I turned this feature on.

Answer (score 0):

You can also submit your issues directly to zen here http://drupal.org/project/issues/zen
Also, Here is
Project Information

```
Maintenance status: Actively maintained http://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/13028
Development status: Under active development http://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/9988
Reported installs: 103049 sites currently report using this theme. View usage statistics.
Downloads: 863,783
```

There should be a news feed to tell you when zen will be adding new features and compabaitabliy...but i cant find it. sorry.

Comment: Thanks.
I fixed the issue by setting the bandwidth optimization to:
Aggregate and compress CSS files. 

Bizzare.

Comment: Yeah drupal can get weird. I will remember this as I am using the zen theme as well. Thanks for the tip. I will add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

you problems solved by just using the powerful omega theme: drupal.org/project/omega -- version 4 is out...

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem with Zen?